# aspnetcore rc2 Local.pubxml How to setup environment during publishing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to publish my aspnetcore rc2 website using Local.pubxml to IIS.

The problem is that I want to change the environment so that I can use `env.IsDevelopment()` and other nice features.

For now, I don't know how to change ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT for:

1. Local.pubxml - Development environment
2. Test.pubxml - Staging environment
3. Live.pubxml - Production environment

Is that possible?

Comment: did you that doc ? : https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html?highlight=environement

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [Asp.Net core doc](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html?highlight=environement) says :

> ASP.NET Core references a particular environment variable,
> Hosting:Environment (or Hosting__Environment on *nix systems), to
> describe the environment the application is currently running in. This
> variable can be set to any value you like, but three values are used
> by convention: Development, Staging, and Production. You will find
> these values used in the samples and templates provided with ASP.NET
> Core.

You setup your environment by `envar`, that's it. There is no .pubxml support.

### UPDATE

As Jos Theeuwen said it's now possible to use **.pubxml** files to set the *ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT* env var for an IIS deployments. see [Windows - IIS deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?highlight=environement&view=aspnetcore-6.0#windows---iis-deployments)

Comment: Thanks, I read this before and want to know if this is the only way. Before in MVC5 it was possible to use web.config transform to change variables for different situations e.g. test and live servers.

Comment: There isn't web.config for ASP.Net Core, only used on IIS

Comment: So you mean that it will be no support of setting environment during publishing using .pubxml?

Comment: I didn't check for the RC2, but yes, its what I mean

Comment: @aguafrommars Can you please explain `You setup your environment by envar, that's it`?  do we add `envar` as xml element in `.pubxml` file?

Comment: @LP13 You should read the doc at https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html?highlight=environement.

Comment: I have already read that but it didn't say anything about `envar`..it mentioned `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` but does not say anything about how to set that during publishing

Comment: @LP13 You don't set it during pushing, but on the environment where you publish the web site (`envar` means environment variable). You can set it per process, user or machine. On IIS for exemple you can configure your application pool identity with this `envar` or set the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT for whole machine

Comment: @aguafrommars Thanks

Answer (score 4):

My apologies for being late to the party, but nowadays you can set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable through web.config, and you can overwrite the value during publish with the .pubxml file. It is right there in the same [ASP.NET Core doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?highlight=environement&view=aspnetcore-2.2) link:

> For Windows IIS deployments: Include the `<EnvironmentName>` property in the publish profile (.pubxml) or project file. This approach sets the environment in web.config when the project is published:
>   
>   `<PropertyGroup>
>     <EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
>   </PropertyGroup>`

I have just tried it with my own custom environment name and it works like a charm.